# Trying to create a Thumbnail gallery in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I've created a page in Wordpress (gallery.php) and I'm trying to attach various images to this page from the media library. How can I do so? I'm not too sure how to call only images to the page without it being a post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While Adding Image OR when you click on Add Media button you can see "Gallery" tab there is button called INSERT GALLERY button at bottom of gallery tab to add attached Images Gallery into Post OR Page

here is some useful reference urls
   - http://en.support.wordpress.com/images/gallery/
   - http://codex.wordpress.org/Gallery_Shortcode
   - [plugin for gallery] [http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/nextgen-gallery/][3](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/nextgen-gallery/)

Regards,
Wordpress Freelance Developer
http://www.santoshkori.com

Answer (score 0):

If you are attaching your images to your gallery page (page with gallery.php as a template?) then you should be able to use get_children.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_children